# Strange javascript issue if statement test = true but won't execute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this click handler code:

```
$('#save').click(function () {
            if (overAllStatus == 'red') {
                rows[lastRowClicked].cells[0].innerHTML = '<a class="modalInput" rel="#flagsSummary" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="/FatcaOne_0/static/images/circleRed.png" width="20" height="20"></a>';
            }
            else if (overAllStatus == "yellow") {
                rows[lastRowClicked].cells[0].innerHTML = '<a class="modalInput" rel="#flagsSummary" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="/FatcaOne_0/static/images/circleYellow.png" width="20" height="20"></a>';
                console.log('Over all status is yellow.');
            }
            else if (overAllStatus == 'greenR') {
                rows[lastRowClicked].cells[0].innerHTML = '<a class="modalInput" rel="#flagsSummary" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="/FatcaOne_0/static/images/circleGreenHollow.png" width="20" height="20"></a>';
            }
            else if (overAllStatus == 'greenN') {
                rows[lastRowClicked].cells[0].innerHTML = '<a class="modalInput" rel="#flagsSummary" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="/FatcaOne_0/static/images/circleGreen.png" width="20" height="20"></a>';
            }
            comments = $('#comments').val();
            $("body").trigger(esc);
            $("#save1").trigger('click');
            redListSize = 0;
            yellowListSize = 0;
            console.log("save clicked");
        });
```

when the value of the variable `overAllStatus` is `yellow` as tested in the JS console and I see this in the console just before I click the 'save' button:

```
> overAllStatus
"yellow"
> overAllStatus == 'yellow'
true
```

I only see "save clicked" printed in the console. It seems like the code in the test condition `(overAllStatus == "yellow")` doesn't execute. I don't understand why.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, please update the tags on your question. And a jsFiddle might help here.

Comment: What does the console print for "overAllStatus == 'red"'?

Comment: If it doesn't execute, then `overAllStatus` isn't `"yellow"`. Put some `console.log()` calls in your code to observe the values as the code runs.

Comment: You could use a "breakpoint" to stop the code and examine variable values!

Comment: Any reason you're not using a `switch` statement?

Comment: I can't reproduce with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5dqg818/), your bug should be related with another part of your code. Also it seems that you're mixing jQuery and classic DOM manipulation, is there a reason for that?

Comment: When are you testing the value of overAllStatus? you could very well have a different value of overAllStatus when save is clicked.

Comment: You may be running into scope problems, be sure that `overAllStatus` is only defined in one place.

Also, try setting Chrome Devtools (or whatever tool you're using) to catch exceptions, possibly an exception is thrown but you're not seeing it (are you sure all the indices exist for `rows[lastRowClicked].cells[0]`?)
Finally, you probably want to think about why one click handler is triggering another.  It would probably be better to separate the handler code from the function that performs the save.

Answer (score 3):

try this replace your code with this one and see what value does "overAllStatus" has within your 'click' callback

```
$('#save').click(function () {
            console.log("overAllStatus", overAllStatus);  //use this to check the value of overAllStatus

            if (overAllStatus == 'red') {
                rows[lastRowClicked].cells[0].innerHTML = '<a class="modalInput" rel="#flagsSummary" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="/FatcaOne_0/static/images/circleRed.png" width="20" height="20"></a>';
            }
            else if (overAllStatus == "yellow") {
                rows[lastRowClicked].cells[0].innerHTML = '<a class="modalInput" rel="#flagsSummary" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="/FatcaOne_0/static/images/circleYellow.png" width="20" height="20"></a>';
                console.log('Over all status is yellow.');
            }
            else if (overAllStatus == 'greenR') {
                rows[lastRowClicked].cells[0].innerHTML = '<a class="modalInput" rel="#flagsSummary" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="/FatcaOne_0/static/images/circleGreenHollow.png" width="20" height="20"></a>';
            }
            else if (overAllStatus == 'greenN') {
                rows[lastRowClicked].cells[0].innerHTML = '<a class="modalInput" rel="#flagsSummary" style="cursor:pointer"><img src="/FatcaOne_0/static/images/circleGreen.png" width="20" height="20"></a>';
            }
            comments = $('#comments').val();
            $("body").trigger(esc);
            $("#save1").trigger('click');
            redListSize = 0;
            yellowListSize = 0;
            console.log("save clicked");
        });
```

Comment: which means "overAllStatus" has no value in it, please search your code to see where it is being define. I suspect did you miss a "var" in front of your variable declaration ? or "overAllStatus" is not define as a global variable.